# How can I use python magic on Heroku as well as local windows machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-magic

My django project uses python-magic. In order to get magic working on my local windows machine, I've had to install python-magic-bin, otherwise I faced the error "ImportError: failed to find libmagic. Check your installation".

But when I push this dependency to my Heroku (linux) server, my build fails with the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin==0.4.14. No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin==0.4.14."

I'm importing magic as "import magic". I've seen another answer here on an old post which said the issue came from using "from magic import magic", but that's not the case here.

What do I need to do to get python-magic working on both setups? I dont want to have to remember to keep python-magic-bin out of the requirements.txt for the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

The current Heroku-20 stack uses Ubuntu 20.04. Pip installs version 0.4.22 of python-magic (https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/). Update the version number in requirements.txt.

Comment: Will that stop the Heroku error of not being able to find python-magic-bin?